# How to animate Google map marker smoothly from one location to another location in ios

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, navigation, marker

i Have a car icon in google map and which have to be moved in regular time interval. the location coordinates will be fetched from server and i have managed to change the location of marker by doing the code below but didint got a smooth movement

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (((self.driverArrival.value(forKey: "latitude")) as AnyObject).doubleValue)!,
                                          longitude: (((self.driverArrival.value(forKey: "longitude")) as AnyObject).doubleValue)!, zoom: 15)

    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((((self.driverArrival.value(forKey: "latitude")) as AnyObject).doubleValue)!, (((self.driverArrival.value(forKey: "longitude")) as AnyObject).doubleValue)!)

    driverMarker.position = position
    driverMarker.map = self.mapView
```

here driverdetails contains all the required data. Just want to know i can use any animation functions to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use animate(to: GMSCameraPosition) to update map position with animation an example will look like this :-

```
func updateMapLocation(lattitude:CLLocationDegrees,longitude:CLLocationDegrees){
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lattitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: 16)
    mapView?.camera = camera
    mapView?.animate(to: camera)
}
```

and call the method like this

```
updateMapLocation(lattitude:-33.8683,longitude:151.2086)
```

[For more information](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views)

**Edit**

For marker position update you can use a single marker and update its position with this code

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2.0)
marker.position = coordindates // CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: i have did this but this is not i wanted, i want to animate the marker in the map not the camera position

Comment: Are you creating a marker everytime you get the new coordinate?

Comment: in above code what i did is like clearing the map view each time and created new marker. But now for the first time added the marker to mapview and then only changing the position

Comment: Yes put a check if marker == nil then initialise it then only update its position and not create marker everytime, declare the marker in your class.

Answer (score 2):

Please Don't use GMSCameraPosition for move pin in the map

You can use mapView.animate(toLocation: YOUR_COORDINATES) method to smoothly move pin in the map

```
self.mapView.animate(toLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: YOUR_LATITUDE, longitude: YOUR_LONGITUDE))
self.marker.position = coordinate
self.marker.map = self.mapView
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: in this case the movement of marker will be smooth?

Comment: yes sure you can try and check?? please refer this documentation[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views#location]

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

Add **GMSMapViewDelegate** to your class,

**self.mapView.delegate = self //Call delegate**

```
//MARK - MapView delegates
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    self.marker.map = mapView;
    self.marker.position = position.target //Your target position
    self.mapView.selectedMarker = self.marker //Your marker
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.marker.snippet = "Getting address... " //Your snippet title 
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView:GMSMapView, idleAt position:GMSCameraPosition) {
    //Get address with village names and street names
    self.getAddressForLatLng(latitude: "\(position.target.latitude)", longitude: "\(position.target.longitude)", zoomLevel: position.zoom)
}
```